# Indentation error in dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indentation

I created a dictionary in Python and keep getting an indentation error. I have checked all the spacing to make sure they are 4 spaces. The other questions similar to this one have all been problems with combining spaces and tabs, but I have used only spaces. I am not sure what it wrong. Please help! Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
class File:
def __init(self):
def open_files(self):
    for x in range(1,3):
        g = b[x]
        f = open(g, 'r')
        vals = f.read()
        f.close()
        vals = vals.split("\n")
        return vals
    mlats = []
    mlt,l = [], []
def get_ml(open_files):
    open_files(self)
    for x in range (0, len(vals)-1):
        tmp = vals[x]
        st = 6
        mlats.append(tmp[st:6+st])
        stx = 4
        sty = 14
        l. append(tmp[stx:stx+7])
        mlt.append(tmp[sty:sty+8])
        return l
        return mlt
    ls = []
def put_l(get_ml):
    get_ml(open_files)
    for x in range(35, len(mlt)-43):
        ls.append(l[x])
    mlts = []
def put_mlt(get_ml):
    get_ml(open_files)
    for x in range(35, len(mlt)-43):
        mlts.append(mlt[x])
```

And here is the error:

```
def open_files(self):
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: You have no body for the `__init` method. Note that that is not the correct spelling of `__init__`. You don't *have* to create such a method, just remove the whole `def` line if you don't need one.

Comment: Not sure if you just entered the code wrong here, but in addition to what everyone else said, you should also tab all of the class functions forward (as well as all of their contents)

Answer (score 2):

Your `__init` function should be `__init__`. And if you don't want that method to do any work, you should be more explicit and `pass`, or as @MartijnPieters mentioned you can just leave this method out entirely.

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Or just not include one.